# Am I allowed to bring a can of olive oil in a check-in luggage?

Tags: air-travel

I would like to bring a 3litres steel can of olive oil in a check in luggage. Is it allowed?

My concerns are:

- it may look suspicious
- it may leak due to pressure difference
- someone may think of it as flammable

Looking for airline agnostic answer but this time flying Singapore Airlines from Sydney to Moscow.

[image]

Comment: Will Moscow allow you to bring in food products?  Having big metal containers in your luggage is sure to grab attention.  I had problem in US with PopTarts (a baked breakfast food sold commercially in individual foil pouches)

Comment: Different context (EU internal flights so regulations might be different) - I lived with some Greeks for a while in England and their family would fly with 3 litre olive oil in the checked luggage between the two countries when they visited (they wanted us to have 'the best').  Never heard of any leakages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in Singapore Airlines baggage regulations, or a random check of a few others, suggests that you cannot pack your olive oil. It's such a valuable commodity, I've done it myself. In a similar, smaller tin, and tripled wrapped in cling film in checked baggage, there were no leaks, or challenges in US customs, although it was declared as a perishable food product.

And nothing in the [Russian Federal Customs Service information](http://eng.customs.ru/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1686&Itemid=1908) suggests that it is limited or prohibited. As a precaution, you would want to include it in your passenger customs declaration, as is generally expected when carrying food products.