# Taking olive oil from Turkey to Germany in check-in luggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, germany, borders, turkey

A friend of mine has relatives in Turkey who produce olive oil by themselves. Now he is travelling there to visit them and we are thinking about to get some of this delicious oil here on his way back.

Would he be allowed to take around 3 - 4 litres of the oil to Germany? Or will this cause any trouble at border control in Turkey or Germany? I'm especially thinking about possible prohibitions of taking foodstuffs from Turkey to Germany.

The question is related to [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95180/am-i-allowed-to-bring-a-can-of-olive-oil-in-a-check-in-luggage), but nevertheless it is a bit different - therefore I ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should careful pack the oil, some airlines requires double layer.

3-4 liters should be OK for Germany, if you import just oil (ev. with few other cheap items).

The only airline I know that has restrictions on olive oil is Aeroflots, and only on flights from Greece to Russia (no such restriction on oil on other flights).